# Is there a way to find out when someone earned a hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013, events

As per title. Does the hat-earning "event" appear in the activity tab, or similar?

Comment: you can check here always http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard for updated rank with hats, if you are in hat war!!!.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't.

If you want to know when *you* earned a hat, you can look at your hatinbox and hatproximate.

Comment: Surely you mean hatproximate.

Comment: @AnnaLear Yes, I did, fixed

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how one earns the Eureka hat. I can't break the cryptic clues :/ I was hoping to find out when someone got one and look at what happened around that time to them.

Comment: @Bohemian Fight club.